# tkinter set scale (create a 2x2 box)

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a 2 by 2 box in python's tkinter, which will be my "world".
Is there a way to set the X and Y axes on the "world"?

Something like:

```
  setXscale(-1.0, +1.0);
  setYscale(-1.0, +1.0);
```

Comment: So you're just looking to create 4 `frame`s in a 2 x 2 grid formation with a fixed size?

Comment: yes. In this box I'll create labels etc

Comment: Just use [`grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) instead of `pack`...

Comment: What do the numbers in this scale represent?  Number of boxes in a row? Number of pixels in a box? Column numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `.pack()` method as can be seen below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

top = Frame(root)
bottom = Frame(root)
topleft = Frame(top)
topright = Frame(top)
bottomleft = Frame(bottom)
bottomright = Frame(bottom)

lbl1 = Label(topleft, text="topleft")
lbl2 = Label(topright, text="topright")
lbl3 = Label(bottomleft, text="bottomleft")
lbl4 = Label(bottomright, text="bottomright")

top.pack(side="top")
bottom.pack(side="bottom")
topleft.pack(side="left")
topright.pack(side="right")
bottomleft.pack(side="left")
bottomright.pack(side="right")

lbl1.pack()
lbl2.pack()
lbl3.pack()
lbl4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This creates a `top` frame and a `bottom` frame, each of which contain a left and right frame.
These frames are then packed in their respective `side`.

---

Alternatively, this can be done a lot easier with `.grid()` like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

topleft = Frame(root)
topright = Frame(root)
bottomleft = Frame(root)
bottomright = Frame(root)

lbl1 = Label(topleft, text="topleft")
lbl2 = Label(topright, text="topright")
lbl3 = Label(bottomleft, text="bottomleft")
lbl4 = Label(bottomright, text="bottomright")

topleft.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
topright.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
bottomleft.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
bottomright.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lbl2.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lbl3.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lbl4.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Or like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

lbl1 = Label(root, text="topleft")
lbl2 = Label(root, text="topright")
lbl3 = Label(root, text="bottomleft")
lbl4 = Label(root, text="bottomright")

lbl1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lbl2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
lbl3.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
lbl4.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```